# remove gnome and install ubuntu-desktop

Tags: gnome, python

I accidentally un-install python from ubuntu. I had ubuntu desktop on it, and then I had to install gnome desktop. Now, I want to come back to Ubuntu-Desktop. I re install it, but when I log in, still the menus are gnome-like. How can I completely remove gnome and re install Ubuntu desktop. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the core gnome parts. This will also remove all dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell gnome-session gnome-control-center gnome-session-flashback gnome-settings-daemon
```

First make sure you have all of the ubuntu components already installed.

```
    sudo apt-get update -y; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
    sudo apt-get install -f
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session unity-control-center unity-settings-daemon
    sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Export display for ccsm and then load  compiz settings manager. And make sure that the ubuntu unity plugin is turned on.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

Or reset compiz back to default and load unity

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Hope this helps.